# Delete Objects in Realm using cascade Relationship

Tags: ios, realm

I have a Class "Person":RLMObject. Now this Class has a property "Dog":RLMObject.
When i delete "Person" object from Realm, it doesn't automatically delete the "Dog" associated with it.

Is there any delete rule in Realm like in Core Data? Help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We are actually working on that feature as we speak, but until it is finally released, you would have to  manually delete the Dog before you delete the Person.

Cheers,

Comment: that's fine. But that also raised a question.i.e.should i use the Realm Beta version for my production application?

Comment: Several people use Realm in production already including http://clothapp.com/, http://www.breezeworks.com/, http://thermodo.com/ and Zynga. Our technology has been in production since 2012 but we’re clearly still working to improve it! Let us know if you have any more questions and if we can do anything to help you make your own decision :)

Comment: Do we have any expected release date for cascading deletion? This is a pretty wanted feature. Realm is really awesome so far, but there are a few things I'm very excited to see released. Thanks @bmunk.

Comment: We have actually reassigned resources to address other (even more important) features, but it's absolutely still on our list. We have now moved all our task tracking publicly to [github issues](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues), so you can see follow our priorities and indicate your needs :-)

Comment: @bmunk Still not a priority nowadays?

Comment: Is is a priority, but unfortunately still a lower priority than other issues. But I would suggest to have the communication in the github issue instead.